# Calculate Send/Receive duration - Outlook

Tags: c++, api, outlook

I'm working on a project that aims at measuring the performance of Microsoft Outlook. My question is "Is there a way to detect send/receive events (start and finish)?". Which API provides methods that are related to this events. I've been googling for a while but I didn't find anything interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Namespace.SyncObjects collection.

SyncObject.SyncStart/SyncEnd events are probably what you want.

EDIT:
Just having a method called `SyncStart` will do absolutely nothing. How would Outlook know that it needs to call your events handler?

You need to subscribe to COM events - both ATL and MFC provide wrappers for the COM events. On the low level, you will need to QI the COM object that raises the events (SyncObject in your case) for IConnectionPointContainer, call  `IConnectionPointContainer::FindConnectionPoint` passing the appropriate disp interface GUID (SyncObjectEvents), then call `IConnectionPoint.Advise` passing your implementation of `IDispatch`. When an event is raised, your implementation of `IDispatch::Invoke()` will be invoked with the appropriate dispid corresponding to the particular event.

Comment: Want it in C++ in fact

Comment: Ok. And what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I'm not able to find which are APIs that help to capture outlook events such as the synchrnization time

Comment: Namespace.SyncObjects object and SyncObject.SyncStart/SyncEnd events. Again, what is the problem that you are having?

Comment: So what is your C++ specific question? Are you having problems accessing the Outlook Object Model in C++ in general? Do you have problem processing COM events? Or something else? There are lots of smart people visiting stackoverflow, but I don't think there are too many psychics here who can read your mind..

Comment: Re @Dmitry : It seems that these aren't the appropriate methods. In fact I tried to show a message box whenever the send\receive operation begins but I got nothing.

Comment: `STDMETHOD_(void, SyncStart)()
 {
  MessageBoxW(NULL,L"SyncStart",L"Hedi Addin",MB_OK);
  return;
 }`
Or am I just doing it wrong? I'm a newbie in Outlook programming

Comment: You need to subscribe to COM events.

Comment: re @Dmitry: Is it possible to determine whther Outlook is downloading emails with their body or only the headers?

Comment: Do you mean in case of an IMAP4 store?

Comment: I meant when Outlook is performing synchronization

Comment: I understand, but what kind of store? IMAP4 or Exchange?

Comment: Exchange, and if possible for both of them

Comment: You can check if a particular message is header only, but I don't think that setting is exposed at all. I don't think the latest version of Outlook even expose that option in the UI.

Answer (score 3):

As Dimitry said, you need to capture the SyncStart and SyncEnd events, probably the easiest way to do this in C++ is creating a Add-in for Outlook, get the correct interfaces and implement the sink objects to get the notifications you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941475%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Edit

Not sure if you managed to make it work, so here a example without addins...

Create a new console application, add these include and imports (change path accordingly) or use the correspondent libid...

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlctl.h>
#import "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\OFFICE12\\mso.dll" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, no_namespace, named_guids, auto_search rename("DocumentProperties", "MsoDocumentProperties") rename("RGB", "MsoRGB") exclude("IAccessible")
#import "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\msoutl.olb" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, named_guids, auto_search rename("Folder", "OlkFolder") rename("CopyFile", "OlkCopyFile") rename("GetOrganizer", "GetOrganizerAE") rename("PlaySound", "OlkPlaySound") rename_namespace("Outlook")
```

Now create a class to receive the events... you only need to derive from IDispatch, I added a HANDLE for a event in order to advise when we are done with the syncronization.

```
class COutlookEventSink : public IDispatch
{
public:
    COutlookEventSink(HANDLE hEvent);
    ~COutlookEventSink(void);

    // IUnknown
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface( REFIID riid, __RPC__deref_out void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject);
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void);
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void);

    // IDispatch
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount(__RPC__out UINT *pctinfo);
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfo(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid, __RPC__deref_out_opt ITypeInfo **ppTInfo);
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNames(
        __RPC__in REFIID riid,
        __RPC__in_ecount_full(cNames) LPOLESTR *rgszNames,
        __RPC__in_range(0,16384) UINT cNames,
        LCID lcid,
        __RPC__out_ecount_full(cNames) DISPID *rgDispId);
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke(       
        DISPID dispIdMember,
        REFIID riid,
        LCID lcid,
        WORD wFlags,
        DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,
        VARIANT *pVarResult,
        EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo,
        UINT *puArgErr);


private:
    long _lRef; 
    HANDLE _hEvent;
};

COutlookEventSink::COutlookEventSink(HANDLE hEvent)
{
    _lRef = 0;  
    _hEvent = hEvent;
}

COutlookEventSink::~COutlookEventSink(void)
{
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE COutlookEventSink::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, __RPC__deref_out void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject)
{
    *ppvObject = NULL;
    if(IsEqualGUID(riid, IID_IUnknown))
        *ppvObject = reinterpret_cast<void**>(this);

    if(IsEqualGUID(riid, IID_IDispatch))
        *ppvObject = reinterpret_cast<void**>(this);

    if(*ppvObject)
    {
        ((IUnknown*)*ppvObject)->AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE COutlookEventSink::AddRef()
{
    return InterlockedIncrement(&_lRef);
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE COutlookEventSink::Release()
{
    if (InterlockedDecrement(&_lRef) == 0)
    {
        delete this;
        return 0;
    }
    return _lRef;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE COutlookEventSink::GetTypeInfoCount(__RPC__out UINT *pctinfo)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE COutlookEventSink::GetTypeInfo(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid, __RPC__deref_out_opt ITypeInfo **ppTInfo)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE COutlookEventSink::GetIDsOfNames(__RPC__in REFIID riid, __RPC__in_ecount_full(cNames) LPOLESTR *rgszNames, __RPC__in_range(0,16384) UINT cNames, LCID lcid, __RPC__out_ecount_full(cNames) DISPID *rgDispId)
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE COutlookEventSink::Invoke(    
    DISPID dispIdMember,
    REFIID riid,
    LCID lcid,
    WORD wFlags,
    DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,
    VARIANT *pVarResult,
    EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo,
    UINT *puArgErr)
{           
    switch(dispIdMember)
    {
    case 61441: // SyncStart - Start a Timer ?
        break;
    case 61444: // SyncEnd
        SetEvent(_hEvent); // We done, exit
        break;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Now on your main create the Outlook application, and add a sink to the SyncObjects

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CComPtr<Outlook::_Application> spApplication;

    HRESULT hr = spApplication.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Outlook::Application), 0, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER );
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && spApplication)
    {
        CComPtr<Outlook::_NameSpace> spSession;

        hr = spApplication->get_Session(reinterpret_cast<Outlook::_NameSpace **>(&spSession));
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spSession)
        {
            CComPtr<Outlook::SyncObjects> spSyncObjects;

            hr = spSession->get_SyncObjects(reinterpret_cast<Outlook::SyncObjects **>(&spSyncObjects));
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spSyncObjects)
            {                                       
                VARIANT index;
                index.intVal = 1;
                index.vt = VT_INT;

                CComPtr<Outlook::_SyncObject> spSyncObject;
                hr = spSyncObjects->Item(index, reinterpret_cast<Outlook::_SyncObject **>(&spSyncObject));
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spSyncObject)
                {                           
                    CComPtr<IConnectionPointContainer> spContainer;
                    HRESULT hr = spSyncObject->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IConnectionPointContainer),reinterpret_cast<void **>(&spContainer));
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spContainer)
                    {   
                        HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

                        CComPtr<COutlookEventSink> spSink = new COutlookEventSink(hEvent);
                        CComPtr<IConnectionPoint> spConnectionPoint;
                        hr = spContainer->FindConnectionPoint(Outlook::DIID_SyncObjectEvents, &spConnectionPoint);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spConnectionPoint)
                        {
                            DWORD dwCookie = 0;                             
                            CComPtr<IUnknown> spUnknown;
                            hr = spConnectionPoint->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&spUnknown));
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spUnknown)
                            {                                   
                                hr = spConnectionPoint->Advise(spSink, &dwCookie);                                          
                                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                {                                   
                                    spSyncObject->Start(); // Syncronize

                                    while(true)
                                    {                                                           
                                        MSG Message;
                                        while(PeekMessage(&Message, NULL, WM_NULL, WM_NULL, PM_REMOVE))
                                        {
                                            TranslateMessage(&Message);
                                            DispatchMessage(&Message);
                                        }   

                                        DWORD dwStatus = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 0); // Wait for end
                                        if(dwStatus == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                                            break;                              
                                    }


                                    spConnectionPoint->Unadvise(dwCookie);                                  
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                                               
                }               
            }
        }

        spApplication.Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @João. I've already read this article and now I'm searching for the appropriate interface for the events I want to capture.

Comment: hi @João, Thanks a lot for the time you spent to write the code. unfortunately it didn't work for me. Your code neither. Wen I run the application Outlook can't run. And when I run Outlook before it, nothing happens. Where could be the problem? I'm using Outlook 2007 (x32) on a x64 machine.

Comment: @HediNaily I didn't tested the code :) and it seems the thread needed to process the messages, check my edit... and now it should work. Also you needed to call Release before calling CoUnitialize().

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is, to get the time interval between two events of outlook. If you plan to do this by C++, I think it will be slightly troublesome. But if you want do some programing over any of MS office application, MS provides an API call Macros(VBA).

In basic:

1. Macro is a add-on program you can write using vb script and that can run in any MS office application on button click or event tiger [more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa209971%28v=office.11%29.aspx).
2. So you can open macro programing interface by opening outlook and then press ALT+F11.
3. So can do lot of things using this macros and you can google for more details.
4. If you need to get some information to C++ application, you ca consider to make API from macro to C++, may be just writing a test file.
5. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044846/run-macro-when-email-is-sent) is some example and you may get some idea from this
6. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is a tutorial about Macro

Hope these ideas may help to achieve your goal.