# Reading mileage field causes mail to get stuck in the outbox

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way to read the mileage field of an email in the Outbox folder without causing the email to get stuck in the Outbox?

In the scope of my app, it is not an option to resend all emails. I must read the value of the field for all emails to decide whether to stop the mail and resend.

It seems reasonable to be required to resend if I modified the mail which I am not. I am merely reading it.

I thought I was on to a solution by reading the object as type "object" instead of "mailitem" but that turned out to be a red herring.

The reading of that property is my very simple and reliable workaround for the problem that the application send_mail event doesn't fire for simple MAPI emails. Unfortunately, it breaks the strategy for other emails.

EDIT
As requested. That ItemSend doesn't always fire is out of my reach is it not?

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next

    InitEvents True    'Reinstantiate the custom handlers if necessary

    If LCase(TypeName(Item)) = "mailitem" Then
        Item.Mileage = ""
        PrepToSendMK166 Item
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Application_ItemSend is triggered by sending. You can read item properties in ItemSend and cancel the send if required. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044846/run-macro-when-email-is-sent

Comment: Yes @niton. I do use application.item send. That is  my normal process. The problem is it doesn't fire for all emails so I need to catch the ones that get missed. Thank you.

Comment: Edit the question to include the code.

Comment: You put ItemSend problems out of reach by improper use of `On Error Resume Next`. Remove it and fix any errors that might appear. See the "A Note Of Caution" section in [Error Handling In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Comment: Well that is interesting. I usually direct errors to an error label but for that function its important to try to let it proceed in the event of the unforeseen. It has fired 100,000's of thousands of times like that and without fail except for the known issue which inspired my question. That is relating to the problem doesn't always fire. this problem. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c25d493-a771-4ded-aa72-d1c63265a98b/applicationitemsend-not-accessed-when-sending-email-outside-outlook-ie-word-or-send-to-mail-from?forum=outlookdev

Comment: If you have code that causes email to get stuck in the Outbox add that to the question. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't have code that causes it. It is a known issue that Outlook doesn't fire the Item Send event if the email was created with simple MAPI. That is the issue I was trying to work around by reading the mileage field on the "Move to Outbox" event. That event does fire. I could use it as resolution were it not for the problem that merely looking at the property halts the send for other messages which, i find, it doesn't do consistently.

Comment: The "Move to Outbox" event code is the problem. If you did not have it mail would not be stuck in the Outbox. Posting the code adds an option of tweaking that code as a solution. See if a copy of the item is seen as touching the item. If not read the property in the copy.

Comment: Thanks @niton. I deferred the expertise of Dmitry regarding the reading of the property of the Outbox item. Subsequent to his answer, I tried a method that produced the desired result but I'm inclined to not trust it. The trick was to not read the object received by the event handler directly but, instead, create a new object using its entry ID and read the property of the new object using the property assessor. It seems that Outlook does not "notice" that I touched it. I will plug it back into the process and post it to get your thoughts on whether it could be reliable. thank. you.

Comment: @niton. Decided not to post. Last night I created a variety of functions and tried every which way to Sunday to make Outlook not "notice" that I looked. That I thought I found a way earlier was a red herring. Dmitry is correct - you cannot touch it. I think its probably a waste of  your time and my time to pursue it. The question re Sent Items event not firing for simple MAPI items has been asked many times. If my planned workaround had hope, someone would have done it before now. I'm throwing in the towel. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Touching a message in the process of being submitted stops the submission. `Application.ItemsSend` event is your last chance to touch the message before it is handed over to the transport provider. Your next opportunity (which is probably too late for you) is when the message is moved to the Sent Items folder and the `Items.ItemAdd` event fires.

There is no solution for what you are trying to do. Also note that the Outbox folder is an eye candy: when using MAPI, a message can be submitted from any folder, not just Outbox.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. I'm not "touching" the email - just "looking".
Of course, App.ItemSend doesn't fire for all emails. That breaks my process which is to use App.ItemSend and SentItems.ItemAdd events in consort.
I was hoping I could detect ones that missed app.ItemSend by reading mileage of the Outbox item. If they are "bad", resend them.
Today I tested reading the Outbox email using a variety of ways to get a handle on the object. Results inconsistent. Sometimes simply "looking" cancels the send, other times not. That lends hope for a resolution.

Comment: Looking is touching - accessing any property or method causes the submission process to abort. After you call Send, the only allowed operation is to release your reference to the message.